# DataGridView shows grey box when loading from List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a List of custom objects that I want to throw into a DataGridView on my form. The objects are parsed from an Excel spreadsheet. I tried doing my parse, and then setting the `DataGridView.DataSource` but no dice- it always displays a grey box!

```
    public Critr()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pLogSheet = LogParser.ParseExcelLog("C:\\working.xlsx");
    }

    private void Critr_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvLogEntries.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dgvLogEntries.DataSource = pLogSheet.Entries;
    }
```

When I debug, I can see that my `pLogSheet.Entries` is in fact being filled, it has three rows of data.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried calling `Refresh()` on the dgv after you've set the data source? Also, please ensure that the [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) property is set to true?

Comment: @Bridge Just tried it, still a grey box. I also set AutoGenerateColumns to true via `dgvLogEntries.AutoGenerateColumns = true` and also no results.

Comment: If you're setting it in code like that, are you sure you're setting that property before you set the datasource?

Comment: @Bridge I moved it right after the `InitializeComponent` call. Still nothing. Would a `DataTable` maybe be a simpler implementation for this?

Comment: You could try manually adding the columns then? There's an example in the documentation I've linked, see the `AddColumns()` method for how to do this.

Comment: I also see from the documentation that `AutoGenerateColumns` will only create columns for public properties of the objects in the datasource - I'm assuming these properties of `Entries` are public? Failing these two, I'm out of ideas I'm afraid!

Comment: And yes, I usually use datatables as datasources for DGVs.

Comment: @Bridge Yep, I double-checked and all my fields are public. It truly is bizarre. I'll try populating a `datatable` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My class set-up was faulty. The class' fields are not recognized by the `DataGridView`, but properties are. So I converted my fields to properties and it worked great!

```
class LogEntry
{
  public string foo;
  public string bar;

  public string fooP { get { return foo; } }
  public string barP { get { return bar; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with `List<T>`. You may copy-paste and try. Have a new Winforms Project and Drag-Drop a `DataGridView control`

Then, you can map your `pLogSheet.Entries` w.r.t. `List<Books>`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class  Books
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int TotalRating { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            var list = new List<Books>
                           {
                               new Books() {Title = "Harry Potter", TotalRating = 5},
                               new Books() {Title = "C#", TotalRating = 5}
                           };
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
        }

    }
}
```